# Add cart meta value for a product after an order request is submitted

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

I have a multi vendor restaurant WooCommerce site. And one person can order max from one restaurant.On a restaurant when adding product to cart I have added an extra meta-field `restaurant_id` which is the id of that restaurant. In a cart , all the products have same `restaurant_id`.

i.e : I have two items in cart having **product_id** : **12** and **13** but they have same **restaurant_id** : **366**.

I need to add this `restaurant_id` as meta-field in `order-complete` or `order-process` action.because i need to show restaurant name on customers account page.

Or any easy way to do that?

### I have tried below code as test

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_field_to_order' );
function add_field_to_order( $order_id ) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'new_field', 'new_value' );
}
```

But it does not add any `meta-field` and `meta-value` to order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**— Update —**

As I understand now, this custom field already exist and you get this restaurant_id value in cart. So you would like to display that in your view order (thank you and my account pages) and may be on emails…

Here is that code:

```
//
// ADD HIDDEN IMPUT FIELDS TO THE CHECKOUT
//
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'checkout_custom_hidden_imput_field' );
function checkout_custom_hidden_imput_field( $checkout ) {
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item){
        $restaurant_id = $item['restaurant_id'];
        break;
    }
    echo '<div id="custom_checkout_fields" class="custom-hidden-checkout-field">
        <input type="hidden" id="restaurant_id" name="restaurant_id" value="'.$restaurant_id.'" />
    </div>';
}

//
// SAVE THE ORDER META WITH FIELD VALUE
//
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['restaurant_id'] ) ) {
        add_post_meta( $order_id, '_restaurant_id', $_POST['restaurant_id'] );
    }
}

//
// DISPLAY FIELD VALUE ON THE ORDER EDIT PAGE (NOT IN CUSTOM FIELDS METABOX)
//
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    $restaurant_id = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_restaurant_id', true );
    if ( ! empty( $restaurant_id ) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>'. __("Restaurant ID", "woocommerce").':</strong> ' . $restaurant_id . '</p>';
    }
}

//
// ADD THE INFORMATION AS META DATA SO THAT IT CAN BE SEEN AS PART OF THE ORDER
//
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','custom_add_values_to_order_item_meta', 1, 3 );
function custom_add_values_to_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    $restaurant_id = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_restaurant_id', true );
    // lets add the meta data to the order!
    wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, '_restaurant_id', $restaurant_id, true);
}
```

*Code goes in any php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin php files.*

Code is tested and works.

Comment: Yes you are right.But i need to add `restaurant_id` to the `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table.Because when a customer logs into his account and goes to `order` page i want to show the restaurant name in that table

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the hook `woocommerce_order_status_XXX`, where XXX is the order status.

For example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_order_status_change_function' );
function my_order_status_change_function( $order_id ) {  
   $order = new WC_Order($order_id);  
   //your logic for updating order meta, the meta is stored in wp_postmeta.  
   update_post_meta( $order_id, 'new_field', 'new_value' );    
}
```

To trigger the function when order status is changed to processing,
change the action name to `woocommerce_order_status_processing`.

Comment: I actually want it when an order request is submitted

Comment: Your test code looks fine, I test it on my site without any problem. Did you add the code in functions.php?

Comment: The meta is not stored in wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta, it is in wp_postmeta.